# Dynamic String Masking in scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, replace, masking

Is there any simple way to do data masking in scala, can anyone please explain. I want to dynamically change the matching patterns to X with same keyword lengths

Example:
patterns to mask:
Narendra\s*Modi
Trump
JUN-\d\d

Input:
Narendra Modi pm of india 2020-JUN-03
Donald Trump president of USA

Ouput:
XXXXXXXX XXXX pm of india 2020-XXX-XX
Donald XXXXX president of USA

Note:Only characters should be masked, i want to retain space or hyphen in output for matching patterns

Comment: This post should help - https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-replace-regular-expression-regex-patterns-in-strings-scala/

Comment: Are you ok with non regex solution ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have an input `String`:

```
val input =
  "Narendra Modi of India, 2020-JUN-03, Donald Trump of USA."
```

Masking off a given target with a given length is trivial.

```
input.replaceAllLiterally("abc", "XXX")
```

If you have many such targets of different lengths then it becomes more interesting.

```
"India|USA".r.replaceAllIn(input, "X" * _.matched.length)
//res0: String = Narendra Modi of XXXXX, 2020-JUN-03, Donald Trump of XXX.
```

If you have a mix of masked characters and kept characters, multiple targets can still be grouped together, but they must have the same number of sub-groups and the same pattern of masked-group to kept-group.

In this case the pattern is *(mask)(keep)(mask)*.

```
raw"(Narendra)(\s+)(Modi)|(Donald)(\s+)(Trump)|(JUN)([-/])(\d+)".r
  .replaceAllIn(input,{m =>
      val List(a,b,c) = m.subgroups.flatMap(Option(_))
      "X"*a.length + b + "X"*c.length
  })
//res1: String = XXXXXXXX XXXX of India, 2020-XXX-XX, XXXXXX XXXXX of USA.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
  val pattern = Seq("Modi", "Trump", "JUN")
  val str  = "Narendra Modi pm of india 2020-JUN-03 Donald Trump president of USA"


  def mask(pattern: Seq[String], str: String): String = {
    var s = str
    for (elem <- pattern) {
      s = s.replaceAll(elem,elem.toCharArray.map(s=>"X").mkString)
    }
    s
  }

  print(mask(pattern,str))
```

out:

```
Narendra XXXX pm of india 2020-XXX-03 Donald XXXXX president of USA
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.. let me know if this will work when my regex pattern is like above edited one

Answer (score 0):

```
scala>  val pattern = Seq("Narendra\\s*Modi", "Trump", "JUN-\\d\\d", "Trump", "JUN")
pattern: Seq[String] = List(Narendra\s*Modi, Trump, JUN-\d\d, Trump, JUN)

scala> print(mask(pattern,str))
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX pm of india 2020-XXXXXXXX Donald XXXXX president of USA
```

Yeah, It should work, try like above.

Comment: in my expected output only characters should be masked not space or '-'. But in here all pattern is masked. let me know if there is a way around for that

Answer (score 0):

Please find the regex and code explanation inline

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object RegExMasking {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    //Regex to fetch the word
    val regEx : String = """(\s+[A-Z|a-z]+\s)""".stripMargin

    //load your Dataframe
    val df = List("Narendra Modi pm of india 2020-JUN-03",
      "Donald Trump president of USA ").toDF("sentence")

    df.withColumn("valueToReplace",
      //Fetch the 1st word from the regex parse expression
          regexp_extract(col("sentence"),regEx,0)
        )
        .map(row => {
          val sentence = row.getString(0)

          //Trim for extra spaces
          val valueToReplace : String = row.getString(1).trim

          //Create masked string of equal length
          val replaceWith  = List.fill(valueToReplace.length)("X").mkString

          // Return sentence , masked sentence 
          (sentence,sentence.replace(valueToReplace,replaceWith))
        }).toDF("sentence","maskedSentence")
      .show()
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like my answer is now outdated due to updated question. But same method can be used to answer the updated question let me if you want me to answer it.